# Unable to brKali Linux 2023.3 RTNETLINK answers: No such device

Tags: linux-networking, wifi, ifconfig, kali-linux

As stated in title, I'm unable to bring any Ralink up.  WLAN0 is in Dormant while WLAN1 is in Default.  Yet nether will come up.  How does one bring it from dormant to default?

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:5572 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5572 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:5372 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5372 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub



# ip link show
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 08:00:27:cb:7e:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 7a:f0:cd:d3:2c:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 9c:ef:d5:fc:74:84
    4: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 06:9e:21:a4:9a:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 9c:ef:d5:fa:9e:cb



 ┌──(root㉿kali)-[/etc/apt]
└─# sudo ip link set wlan1 down
                                                                                            
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/etc/apt]
└─# sudo ip link set wlan1 up  
RTNETLINK answers: No such device
                                                                                            
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/etc/apt]
└─# sudo ip link set wlan0 down
                                                                                            
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/etc/apt]
└─# sudo ip link set wlan0 up  
RTNETLINK answers: No such device
```